# Can't use SMB2 on Windows XP: Is there any way to enable or install SMB2 in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, samba

I have a Windows XP machine which I need to read files from using Samba.

I'm developing a service that uses the [EzSmb Nuget](https://github.com/ume05rw/EzSmb). The read process from the Windows XP Samba share folder should be following:

1. Open connection
2. Rename data csv file to temporary name (A process on XP machine will every minute log information to this csv file. If it doesn't exist it's created again)
3. Read renamed file and save in server SQL
4. Delete renamed file
5. Close connection

The EzSmb library provides a “Move” command which copies/move a file to a new location with a given name. I can't get this to work. I noticed that this function doesn't support SMB1 which Windows XP uses.

My question is, is there any way to enable or install SMB2 in Windows XP?

Comment: Windows XP is EOL for around 13 years now. Unlikely to find support for it.

Comment: @mashuptwice When googling for possible solutions several sites provides this information "NOTE: SMB2 will still be enabled with a new install of PVS 7.13". But what is this PVS?

Comment: @JohanAhlqvist AFAIK, XP doesn't support SMBv1 - if there is a workaround, ask on the Spiceworks [forum](https://community.spiceworks.com/windows), as Microsoft has vendor reps that monitor the forum and engage. General FYIs: XP is unsafe to use unless on a Microsoft enterprise LTS plan _(when Microsoft patches vulnerabilities, it shows how to exploit the vulnerabilities on unpatched systems, such as EOL Windows versions)_. SMBv1 isn't safe to use at all, as it's been actively exploited daily for several years.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for the hints. Yes I know that both XP and Smb1 are highly unsafe but those requirements are out of my control.

Comment: Microsoft released a security patch for smb on XP March 14, 2017, see Related Resources link for info on the patch>>>>>https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55245

Comment: AFAIK Windows XP does not support SMB2, only SMB1.

Comment: My recollection was that SMB2 was available with XP SP2, but mabey I'm thinking of NTLMv2.

Comment: Thanks all for valuable feedback

Answer (score -1):

No, Windows XP stops at SMB1.
Not sure which direction you were after but in Samba's "smb.conf"  (NT1=SMB1) you can set the global parameters:

```
# Samba client accessing Windows XP share.
client min protocol = NT1

# Windows XP client accessing Samba server.
server min protocol = NT1
ntlm auth = ntlmv1-permitted
```

Note that this will severely downgrade the security of the Samba server!